# Can gradle download dependencies from websites which are not maven?

Tags: gradle, request, gradle-plugin

I'm starting learning gradle and I want to make a gradle plugin,however there are some jars(such as minecraft.jar)which aren't come from any maven repository,so I want to ask,can gradle api download resources which come from other websites?
If can,how to do this?

Comment: there are other repositories like jcentral , mavencentral which can be used for this , even we can have own repository e.g.`maven {
      url = "your url"
        }` for minecraft this can be used `maven {
            name = "forge"
            url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
        }`

Comment: You misunderstood this，I want to get a jar which is not a maven repository such as pan.baidu.com or google cloud.

Comment: yes i got it ,that you can inside the url you can give any artifactory name , let it be be a jfrog or nexus baidu or google if it has any..